# Slow hostname resolution for SSH(git)

Tags: ssh, dns, git, hostname, host-name-resolution

Strangest thing. After upgrading to Fedora 33, the `git` `fetch`, `push` and `pull` commands are SLOW.

I've been able to get a bit of trace and debug info using the following command:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch 2>&1 |  gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
```

... so it appends info like so to stdout...

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch 2>&1 |  gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
[2020-11-25 19:14:01] 19:14:01.239274 git.c:444               trace: built-in: git fetch
[2020-11-25 19:14:01] 19:14:01.240644 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 'ssh -vvv' -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''thomasmatecki/dots.git'\'''
[2020-11-25 19:14:01] OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h FIPS 22 Sep 2020
[2020-11-25 19:14:01] debug1: Reading configuration data /home/thomas/.ssh/config

...
[2020-11-25 19:14:01] debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
[2020-11-25 19:16:16] debug2: ssh_connect_direct
[2020-11-25 19:16:16] debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.4] port 22.
[2020-11-25 19:16:16] debug1: Connection established.
...
```

... and two whole minutes later it completes. THAT'S TOO LONG. Note, that the `resolving "github.com" port 22` step takes 2 whole minutes.

I'm not sure what to do next. How might one troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Is it only this slow when you use git or is it the same problem if you try to reach github.com from a web browser? Also, is it always this slow or only the first time when it tries to resolve the hostname?

Comment: Oddly enough, It was slow when using firefox BUT not when using chrome. It is always slow.

Comment: I guess Chrome might cache the DNS response or use Google DNS when the normal one takes too long. Try running `dig github.com` and post the output, that should tell us how the system is trying to resolve the name, though I am not sure what DNS lookup system would take 2 minutes.